# Get thumbnail URL :)

Tags: images

I try to get thumbnail URL correctly...

In my functions.php, I have theses lines:

```
<?php
add_theme_support( 'post-thumbnails' );
set_post_thumbnail_size( 'emphasis', 132, 82, true );
?>
<?php
function w_thumbnail_src() {
    if (has_post_thumbnail()) {
        $thumb = wp_get_attachment_image_src(get_post_thumbnail_id(), 'emphasis');
       echo $thumb[0]; // thumbnail url
    }
}
?>
```

The thing is, I don't get the correct size in my template :(
I have this:

```
<?php w_thumbnail_src(); ?>
```

That returns the big image, not the thumbnail :(

Where am I wrong?

Regards,
Alex

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are not using [`set_post_thumbnail_size`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/set_post_thumbnail_size) properly.
Try with:

```
add_image_size( 'emphasis', 132, 82, true );
```

Comment: I see... Big thanks.
What if I don't want to refer to the size in the function, but in the template itself? So I can use the same function for different image size?

And set in my template, something like:
    <?php w_thumbnail_src('emphasis'); ?>

Big thanks anyway :)

Comment: You may use the following modified code:
`function w_thumbnail_src($size = 'thumbnail') {
        if (has_post_thumbnail()) {
            $thumb = wp_get_attachment_image_src(get_post_thumbnail_id(), $size);
           echo $thumb[0]; // thumbnail url
        }
    }`
You may pass the desired size, and if you don't it will use the default thumbnail size.

Comment: Many thanks Marco. It's working perfectly. And now, I understand how to create "dynamic" functions. So thank you :)

Answer (score 2):

You are using the wrong function to set the size of the image.  You want to use `add_image_size('emphasis', 132, 82, true );`  `set_post_thumbnail_size()` sets the default post thumbnail size and does not accept a name attribute.